# Blocking Submit Button in Jquery for certain rules

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to perform some jQuery validation based on comment form input and it is partially working and also showing some wired behavior. So, any of you guys can help it will be really helpful.

This is the code that I wrote:

```
$('body.single-post #submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('form#commentform').keyup(function() {
    /*Checking if name is provided*/
    if ( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#author').val() )  == '' ) {
        $('p.comment-form-author').append('<span id="nameNotice">Please enter your name</span>');
    } else {
        $('#nameNotice').remove();
    }
    /*Checking if email is provided*/
    if ( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#email').val() )  == '' ) {
        $('p.comment-form-email').append('<span id="emailNotice">Please enter a valid email</span>');
    } else if ( isEmail( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#email').val() ) ) == false ) {
        $('p.comment-form-email').append('<span id="emailNotice">This is not a valid email</span>');
    } else {
        $('#emailNotice').remove();
    }
    /*Checking if comment is provided*/
    if ( $.trim( $('form#commentform textarea#comment').val() ).length  < 10 ) {
        $('p.comment-form-comment').append('<span id="commentNotice">Comment must be at least 10 charecters</span>');
    } else {
        $('#commentNotice').remove();
    }
    if ( ( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#author').val() )  != '' ) &&
         ( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#email').val() ) != '' ) &&
         ( $.trim( $('form#commentform textarea#comment').val() ).length  > 10 ) 
        ){

        $('body.single-post #submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('body.single-post #submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having with this script is -

1. When I'm entering name then email & them comment (in textaread) the button not getting enabled bu it's own, but it should be. But when I first type the comment (in textarea) then name/email - then the button is getting enabled. Very wired. No idea why.
2. Also the script is only working when the text gets removed by keyboard backspace, if I remove it by selecting via mouse and then backspace the whole, the button stayed enabled. It is only getting disabled if I remove each text via backspace.

I also wanted to show up some message like if the filed is empty then it will show "Please enter your name" and when it will fill up it will vanish again. Again if he backspace the entry then it will show up the message again. So I tried something like this:

```
if ( ( $.trim( $('form#commentform input#author').val() )  != '' ) ) {
        $('p#something').append("<span>Please enter name</span>");
    }
```

But in that case it just keep adding it over and over every time the fields gets empty.

Any idea guys?

Comment: You do realise there are various jQuery form validation libraries which do this stuff, don't you? Never write your own code if someone else has already done it for you.... e.g [this one](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you've the following HTML. I've made it running for you. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3h35h95L/)

```js
$('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('form#commentform').keyup(function() {

    if ( ( $.trim( $('#author').val() )  != '' ) &&
         ( $.trim( $('input#email').val() ) != '' ) &&
         ( $('#comment').val().length  > 3 ) 
        ){

        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<form id="commentform">
    <input type="text" required id="author"></br>
    <input type="email" required id="email"></br>
       <textarea required id="comment"></textarea></br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And last, for validation part i've simply used HTML5 attributes. They'll take care of it. If you still need a custom validation then you've to write your regex patterns.

Comment: thats al right. but why you removed the trim from the comment textarea? Also any idea how to show up the message as I said above?

Comment: Hey you use the `$.trim()` there, no issue. And for showing the error messages you'v have to first match it through regex ie- `/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i` used for email validation etc. Then show the error message wherever you want

Comment: Yah I know the regex part. But can u show me how to do it for the name field where no regex is required? As you can see in my above code the way I did it using `append` it just keep staying there and not going away. Just keep adding the text over and over

Comment: Don't use `append`, use `text()` instead.

Comment: so if I use `text()` will it automatically goes away when the field has some value and then again come up when its blank?

Comment: Clear it ie- `$('p#something').text('')` in the `else` of your check. It'll keep updating as you're matching it on each `keyup`

Comment: Hmm. got it. But still having the same issue. Hold on sharing a video recording

Comment: Why don't you keep updating it on fiddle? It'll be much easier to understand with it

Comment: It works in fiddle. Lol you have it in your fiddle. Its a wired issue thats why I wanna show it to you. Watch - http://www.screencast.com/t/9UdTIOWRAuhP (sorry for the back noice) (1min 20sec video)

Comment: Hope u see the wired issue now. Cant show u this in fiddle.

Comment: Mystery solved: Use `$('form#commentform').keyup()` not `$('form#commentform input').keyup()` otherwise it'll work only on inputs not with textarea. By the way in my code i'd mentioned it already.

Comment: lol. Overlooked. Thanks a lot for all your helps and solving the mystery for me. :)

Comment: It seems not to be working as I wanted doe to the KeyPress event. Updated the code above. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I couldn't understand your requirement. Please update the fiddle, not the code above. Even i can't see it to be working.

Comment: Ok will update the fiddle and give you the link in few hours.

Comment: Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/114znuro/2/
Sorry, I should have gave you the fiddle earlier. But didn't get time to create it. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Yes I have seen you have used `text()` which I also have tried but the problem with it is that it is adding the text just after starting the `<p>` while I wanna add it before ending of `</p>`, that is why I used `append()`. Hope you got the point now.

Comment: Then put that notice span elements before the paragraph tag, simple